# Javascript redrawing table after getting response from Rails Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

EDIT:

I want my Index to change according to Price descending and Price ascending just like Amazon.

Right now, I send an ajax request to the site, with the new value of the select requesting the data. The site gets the data from database and sorts it.

How can my javascript get the sorted books response and redraw the cards in my index page?

BookController.rb

```
def index
  if params.dig("book", "title").nil? && params.dig("users", "university").nil?
    @books = Book.where({title: params.dig("book", "title")})
    .joins(:user).where(users: {university: params.dig("users", "university")})
  elsif !params.dig("book", "title").nil? && params.dig("users", "university").nil?
    @books = Book.where({title: params.dig("book", "title")})
  elsif params.dig("book", "title").nil? && !params.dig("users", "university").nil?
    @books = Book.joins(:user).where(users: {university: params.dig("users", "university")})
  else
    @books = Book.all
  end
  case params[:sort]
    when "Price Descending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "DESC")
    when "Price Ascending"
      @books.order(price_cents: "ASC")
    else
      @books.sort_by(&:created_at)
  end
end
```

Book Index.html.erb

```
<select id="priceSelect">
  <option value="Best Results" selected="selected">Best Results</option>
  <option value="Price Descending">Price Descending</option>
  <option value="Price Ascending">Price Ascending</option>
</select>

.
.
.

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 selectable-card">
    <%= link_to book_path(book.id) do %>
      ...   
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('#priceSelect').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "books",
      type: "GET",
      data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
    })
  });
</script>
```

And lastly my routes.rb

```
resources :books do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: The process is quite involved. Less so if you can live with reloading the whole page. Here's the outline: 1) attach `change` handler on the select; 2) in it, send an ajax request to the site, with the new value of the select, requesting data; 3) site gets data from database, sorts accodingly and responds to the ajax request; 4) javascript on your page sees the response and redraws the table.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple do the following. There are better ways to do this but, for you following can be done with minimal logic changes, give your select an Id such as "sort"

```
@books = Book.order(price: sort_order.to_sym)

private

def sort_order
  return "Asc" if params[:sort].nil?
  return params[:sort] == "Price Descending" ? "Desc" : "Asc"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but by doing this, the books are already sorted. I want the books to start sorting when the User clicks on the select and chooses price asc or price desc.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following code

```
def index
 @books = Book.all
 case params[:sort]
 when "Price Descending"
   @books.order(price: "DESC")
 when "Price Ascending"
   @books.order(price: "ASC")
 else
  # add the best results query here
 end
end
```

Please modify your script code to this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#sort').change(function(){
  var sort = $('#sort :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
     url: "books/index",
     type: "GET",
     data: {sort: $('#sort :selected').val()},
    })
 });
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: I changed my select to <select id="sort"> and did what you told me, but params[:sort] gives me nil. shouldn't the params be "Best Results" since I chose this as default?

Comment: @WenqingKevinMa params[:sort] is showing nil is because you are using "selectPrice" as a params key to the ajax request. Please change "selectPrice" to "sort" in your ajax request. i.e     data: {selectPrice: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()}    change to     data: {sort: $('#priceSelect :selected').val()},

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, I think we got confused because of the names. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes this looks correct to me. Please let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Unfortunatly, it does not work. When i change the select value and click on i.e. Price Descending the Page does nothing. I think there is something wrong with my Ajax? Also, @books.order(price_cents: sort_order.to_sym) only gives me something when I changed return params[:sort] == "Price Descending" ? "Desc" : "Asc" to "desc" and "asc"

Comment: Please make sure your ajax is working i,e the request is triggered to server when changing the value from select list.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check and let me know if still you face an issue.

Comment: Do you think that it has something to do with the routes? Because I actually get some params from the previous Page, so the Index is different from just Book.all . Please take a look at my updated Edit.

Comment: I think you want to achieve the functionality without reloading the page. If so then you need to make these specific changes 1. create new function 2. add route to function 3. create new partial which displays books in table 4. on chnage call ajax to the new function 5. add the logic to new function 6. create js.erb file for new function 7. render the partial  in js.erb file